# On the language use of quantum mechanics: "state $\rho$" or "density matrix $\rho$ of the mixed state"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, terminology, density-operator, quantum-states

For pure states one usually uses the bra-ket Notation and then uses language e.g. "the state $|\psi>$..."

Is it also common to say similarly for mixed states, which are usually written as a density operator? E.g. "the mixed state $\rho$..."? Or is this not used in favor of the language use as e.g. "the density matrix $\rho$ of this mixed state...$ (without declaring a symbol for the state).

Comment: I've often heard people say "the state $\rho$". Generally physicists try to omit needless words.

Comment: I mean, if you're in an introductory course they might be careful about it to make sure everybody is following. But afterwards people know what you mean if you use any version.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's common. From a technical perspective, it's far more accurate to call $\rho$ a state than it is to call $|\psi\rangle$ a state because for any nonzero complex number $\lambda$,  $|\psi\rangle$ and $\lambda |\psi\rangle$ correspond to precisely the same (pure) state. In other words, pure states should not be identified with specific ket vectors but rather with *equivalence classes* of vectors, and this distinction is sometimes quite important. There is no such ambiguity with density matrices.